# Web API post array but frombody is always null

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have array in the following format which i need to post to an API :

> console.log(addserverList);

[image: Array]

I want to pass this to a post method of api

```
   const options = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};
            return this.http.post(           'http://localhost:54721/api/BulkUpload/SaveBulkUploadData',addserverList,options)
```

I am able post to api, but the data passes is always showing as NULL

[image: Null value]

Model i structured like below:

[image: model]

**Function to generate array**

```
private extractData(res: Response) {

        let csvData = res['_body'] || '';
        let allTextLines = csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        let headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
        let lines = [];

        for ( let i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
            // split content based on comma
            let data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
            if (data.length == headers.length) {
                let tarr = [];
                for ( let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                    tarr.push(data[j]);
                }
                lines.push(tarr);
            }
        }
        this.csvData = lines;

       // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.csvData));
        this.saveBulkUpload();  
      }
```

Comment: You are posting an array of string arrays, not an array of objects that map to the desired model.

Comment: [Post information as text and not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) will increase chance of getting solution.

Comment: There's no way ASP can properly deserialize an array of `string[]` to `List<AddServer>`.

Comment: what should be the alternative?

Comment: depends on whether the data being sent is malformed or if the expectation is incorrect

Comment: how to convert the above array to this json format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON is an array of arrays. The method is expecting an array of objects which match the format of the `AddServer` class.

Your JSON should look something like this:

```
[
   {
        "HostName": "Server1", 
        "Type1": "type1_1", 
        "Type2": "type1_1", 
    },
    {
        "HostName": "Server2", 
        "Type1": "type1_2", 
        "Type2": "type2_2",  
    }
]
```

**Change to function**

This has required some guesswork as I don't know the service contract which is feeding into the function but what needs to be changed is in the loop.

```
for ( let i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        // split content based on comma
        let data = allTextLines[i].split(',');

        if (data.length == headers.length) {
            let tobj = {};

            tobj.HostName = data[0];
            tobj.Type1= data[1];
            tobj.Type2= data[2];

            lines.push(tobj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to convert the above array to this json format?

Comment: It depends on how are you generating the array in first place. Are you creating it manually in JavaScript?

Comment: yes its generated manually through angular typescript function

Comment: If you post the function then it may be possible to show you how to edit it produce the correct JSON. Essentially though you need to populate the parent array with java script objects rather than child arrays of strings. IF you're not familiar with these a good guide can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

Comment: Thank you so much for the support, it worked like a charm, your efforts are commendable.Thank you again!